# how to increase res time in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I have 70 million points in Lidar '.las' binary file.

using @loaders.core & @loaders.las, I got points details and save it to json file.
but due to high number of points I cant save it to one file.
that is why I save 5 million points in one file and than create new file.
time taken to create these files is around 5 min
but after creating all 14 files, once again post request trigger and start the same process.

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    console.log('upload started');
    if (req.files) {

        var file = req.files.file
        const data = load(file.data, LASLoader);
        data.then((e) => {
            var points = Object.values(e.attributes.POSITION.value)
            
            while (points.length) {
                var b = points.splice(0, 5000000);
                fs.writeFileSync('./public/assests/user' + filename + '.json', JSON.stringify(b));
                filename++
            }
            console.log("done array");

            res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/pointerLoad.html')
           
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: 70million items in `e.attributes.POSITION.value`? imo you should avoid the hang by storing the file as-is, create a queue and give them back an operation/job id which can be processed another way. why are you making files and not using a db?

Comment: I want to use these 70millions points in threeJs. So I saved into files and use in my threejs code file 'pointerLoad.html' file. is there any other way I can use it in my threejs code